# when i try to parse an xml file in java i am getting invalid arguments exceptions . i am using dom parser to parse ....the

Tags: java, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"> <SOAP-ENV:Header/> <SOAP-ENV:Body>  <m:Inform xmlns:m="urn:dslforum-org:cwmp-1-0">  <m:DeviceId xsi:type="soap-enc:type"><m:Manufacturer xsi:type="xsd:string">arg</m:Manufacturer><m:OUI xsi:type="xsd:string">arg</m:OUI><m:ProductClass xsi:type="xsd:string">arg</m:ProductClass><m:SerialNumber xsi:type="xsd:string">TR106</m:SerialNumber></m:DeviceId><m:Event xsi:type="soap-enc:arrayType"><m:EventStruct><m:EventCode xsi:type="xsd:string">6 CONNECTION_REQUEST</m:EventCode></m:EventStruct></m:Event><m:MaxEnvelopes xsi:type="xsd:unsignedInt">1</m:MaxEnvelopes><m:CurrentTime xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2011.02.29 AD at 05:03:25 PM IST </m:CurrentTime><m:RetryCount xsi:type="xsd:unsignedInt">0</m:RetryCount><m:ParameterList xsi:type="cwmp:ParameterValueStruct[5]"><m:ParameterValueStruct><m:name xsi:type="xsd:string">Device.DeviceInfo.HardwareVersion</m:name><m:value xsi:type="xsd:string">arg</m:value></m:ParameterValueStruct><m:ParameterValueStruct><m:name xsi:type="xsd:string">Device.DeviceInfo.SoftwareVersion</m:name><m:value xsi:type="xsd:string">arg</m:value></m:ParameterValueStruct><m:ParameterValueStruct><m:name xsi:type="xsd:string">Device.ManagementServer.ConnectionRequestURL</m:name><m:value xsi:type="xsd:string">arg</m:value></m:ParameterValueStruct><m:ParameterValueStruct><m:name xsi:type="xsd:string">Device.ManagementServer.ParameterKey</m:name><m:value xsi:type="xsd:string">ABC1000</m:value></m:ParameterValueStruct><m:ParameterValueStruct><m:name xsi:type="xsd:string">Device.LAN.IPAddress</m:name><m:value xsi:type="xsd:string">arg</m:value></m:ParameterValueStruct></m:ParameterList></m:Inform> </SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: I've seen this question before...

Comment: There was a reason, that the older posting has been deleted...

Comment: @user692527 - unreadable again - required information missing agein (*who* throws the exception -> code & stacktrace needed)

Comment: i have caught the exceptions and i am printing them

Comment: i have caught the exceptions and printed them..... i am able to get the soap envelope from the soap message and then the body part from the soap message ... but then when try to get the first child , it s causing some problems ... i am not able to get localname for that child its null ... and then when i try to get further childs , its giving exceptions ... i am getting the output as #text when i try to get the node name and node type from the first child ..

Answer (score 0):

Some more information about the error would be nice, so I'm just guessing: Your `xsd:dateTime` `2011.02.29 AD at 05:03:25 PM IST` looks suspicious, see  http://books.xmlschemata.org/relaxng/ch19-77049.html for valid examples.

Comment: i think date should not be any problem ..... and about the exceptions the code is throwing the exceptions... i have caught the exceptions and printing them.... i am able to get the envelope from the soap message and then i am able to get the body part from the soap message and print it ..... then i am using msg=getbodyAsDom () method and getting the first child .... i am able to get the first child and that child is not null but then i am not able to parse from then onwards .

Comment: continued----->like once i get the child that is Node node =msg.getFirstChild(); and then i am not able to get any attributes like node.getArgumentList is all null .... node.getLocalName() is also returning nulll .... what i want to stress is i get node type as #text when i print to print node type and node name ........ any more info needed then pls let me know ......

Comment: @darioo , can u pls let me know where is the similar question asked.... can u pls send me the link ...